# Allow additional event info inputs with FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

By default only the "Title" field property of an event can be added.

1: How can I edit the "Add Event" popup to allow additional of extra fields?

2: Also, is it possible to have the start/end times shown in the popup?
 
I'd like to allow the user fine tune the times rather than relying on the drag and drop method i.e. Allow user enter 12:05, 13:52, etc...

Maybe I need to implement my own popup solution triggered by setting some attribute?

Code example would be great if possible.

I working off the latest verion 1.6.4.
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, my bad guys!

Here is my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header : {
            left : 'prev,next today',
            center : 'title',
            right : 'agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView : 'agendaDay',
        selectable : true,
        selectHelper : true,
        select : function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            if (title) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    title : title,
                    start : start,
                    end : end,
                    allDay : allDay
                }, true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable : true,
    })
});
```

I simply need to add the extra fields to my prompt (Or show/hide a modal form).